# Magento Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup'

Tags: magento, fatal-error

I have a  problem.:

Fatal error: Class ‘Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup’ not found in /home/growth14/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Model/Resource/Setup.php on line 35

I’ve checked the SVN & have uploaded both versions of the “Setup.php” in question:

http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.7/app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Model/Resource/Setup.php

http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.7-trunk/app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Model/Resource/Setup.php

However, there’s been no change. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It says that your class in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Setup.php is missing, or has the wrong class name in it.

Please check if the following file is available, or if any overrides have been made:
http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Setup.php

The files you have checked are the files from which the missing class have been called.